# How to run & open Excel file from server?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an Excel file installed with Add-Ins. If I share the excel sheet with other person, the sheet requires the same add-in to work.

Is it possible to place my excel in common repository and users can use it ?

or is there any other way to do it ?

In My case, I have added **Office 2003 Add-in: Office Web Components** from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=22276

but if others access the sheet, they too need the add-in installed. They do not have admin access to install it.

or is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: To me this seems like any other custom software solution you deploy to users.  It always requires that the components they reference are installed ahead of time on the target machine or else can be installed on demand by your deployment package.  If I were doing this in the environment where I work, I would setup a special Active Directory group policy to deploy the add-in to the users who need it, and then I might deploy the Excel file centrally (on the network) so those users could get to it.

Comment: you meant , should the user also deploy it from active directory ?

Comment: The user wouldn't; the IT department (or whoever is the administrator) would.

Comment: i know it should be installed by IT department but i am looking for accessing components from one location rather than hurting each and every user . .